# ModelForm extra field is missing

Tags: django

I have the following structure:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    # ...

class ModelB(models.Model):
    modela = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
    # ...
```

And a form for `ModelA`: `ModelAForm`. By default, a field for `modelb_set` does not exist because it is a reverse relationship, so I tried adding it to the form:

```
class ModelAForm(forms.ModelForm):
    modelb_set = forms.SelectMultiple()

    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        exclude = []

    def __init___(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...
        self.fields['modelb_set']  # this throws KeyError
```

Why is a `KeyError` thrown when trying to access that field, when I explicitly declared it in the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SelectMultiple - like Select etc - is a widget, not a field. You need to use actual fields here. The appropriate one to use would probably be [ModelMultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield), which takes a queryset.

Note, you'll need to add some custom save logic as well - Django won't know what to do with that field.

Comment: Ah, right... What if I want choices instead of queryset though?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Of course you can use the plain MultipleChoiceField. But you'll need to generate the choices from a queryset anyway, so why not pass the queryset directly?